# "junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null" in Grails Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails

I'm new to grails and am trying to get some tests running. I have two classes:

```
class Category {
    String name;
}

class Animal {
    Category category1
    Category category2

    boolean addCategory(Category category) {
        if (!category1) {
            category1 = category
            return true
        }
        else if (!category2) {
            category2 = category
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    boolean hasCategory(Category category) {
        return category1 == category || category2 == category
    }
}
```

Now I wrote a test that should check that adding more than two categories fails and that the third category would not be part of the categories:

```
class AnimalTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testMaximumCategories() {
        Category category1 = new Category(name: "Category 1")
        Category category2 = new Category(name: "Category 2")
        Category category3 = new Category(name: "Category 3")

        Animal animal = new Animal(title: "Animal")
        assertTrue(animal.addCategory(category1))
        assertTrue(animal.addCategory(category2))
        assertFalse(animal.addCategory(category3))

        assertTrue(animal.hasCategory(category1))
        assertTrue(animal.hasCategory(category2))
        assertFalse(animal.hasCategory(category3))
    }
}
```

This test always fails in the last line and the stacktrace is the following

```
null
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:34)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1323)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeStaticMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1082)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.callStatic(StaticMetaClassSite.java:62)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:165)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:173)
at animal.AnimalTests.testMaximumCategories(AnimalTests.groovy:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When I copy/pasted your code it failed since there's no `title` property in the `Animal` class. This might be an artifact of converting real code to demo code, but it could cause some compiler weirdness. Try running `grails clean` to force a full compile. Once I added a `title` field it worked fine.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that hint. It wasn't the title but another attribute in the Category instances I forgot to set :)